# Netbeans remove broken svn project entry

Tags: svn, netbeans

I have 2 projects which use to be linked to a svn server I dont use anymore. After creating the project in Netbeans, Netbeans found the .svn folders in the project and assumed that it was still linked to the SVN server.

I then removed the project from netbeans (but kept the source code), closed Netbeans and went to the project folder and removed all .svn folders and other config files within the project folder.

I went back into Netbeans and recreated the project. This time it appears that Netbeans does not think it's linked to a SVN server, but when I go to Team > Subversion > Import into repository, nothing happens. There is no dialog or error message or anything, just nothing happens.

If I copy the source files to another folder (or rename the project folder) I am then able to import into repository perfectly, but that means I have to leave the project folder named differently which is a workaround but not the solution.

I assume there is an entry in some config file Netbeans uses to "remember" which projects (or folders) is linked to Subversion, and if I can edit that and remove the entry I suppose it would work.

Has anyone run into a similiar issue or know where or how I can correct this?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

I can also confirm that if I copy the same project into a new folder (say the first project was called projectname.com and I copy the same folder with its contents and name it projectsname2.com) I am able to import into repository. It definately has to do with the original projectname.com folder name linked or providing broken svn configurations.

Comment: Did you try deleting the SVN cache of netbeans? (`%HOME%\.netbeans\7.x\cache\svn` or `%HOME%\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\Cache\7.x\svncache` depending on the version)

Comment: @madth3: Genius :) I'm running Netbeans 7.3 on Windows 8. The cache folder is located under %HOME%\AppData\Local\Netbeans\Cache\7.3 - Cleared it and it works! If you want to submit this as an answer I'll gladly accept :)

Comment: Just to make sure, deleting the cache folder (well, deleting all of the cache files), how would that impact the rest of my projects which is linked correctly to SVN? @madth3

Comment: Usually, when I faced a SVN problem I just deleted the svn part of the cache but I've added some references in my answer for your peace of mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen this particular problem but an old solution that solves many SVN problems in NetBeans is deleting the Subversion related cache.

This is a folder whose name and location changed recently:

- In Netbeans prior to 7.2  it was a folder `svn`, full path: `%HOME%\.netbeans\7.x\var\cache\svn`
- In Netbeans 7.2+ it's a folder `svncache` with full path: `%HOME%\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.x\svncache`
- For locations in other systems see the [Netbeans wiki entry on userdir/cachedir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)

Deleting the cache folder (while NetBeans is closed, mind you) forces NetBeans to re-read SVN information from the working copy. Therefore, the Subversion operations might take a few seconds more the next time they're invoked.

The linked wiki page states:

> The NetBeans cachedir is a directory consisting of files that may become large, may change frequently, and can be deleted and recreated at any time.